Xunit Test Result Attachments are not displayed
We are using C# selenium and Xunit(2.7.0) for out automation. We have a visual studio test task that triggers 'Test Runs' through test selections. Currently we are following this Attachments - Create Test Result Attachment  to upload test log files. We dont get any issues with respect to the uploader logic, but we are not able to see any attachments. Here is our logic - This is how we call the uploader
 try
 {
     // Run asynchronous upload operations asynchronously
     Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         try
         {
             // Upload log file
             string pat = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT");
             string runId = devOpsUploader.GetLatestRunId(pat);
             var testResults = await devOpsUploader.FetchTestResults(runId);
             string testCaseResultId = testResults.FirstOrDefault()?.Id.ToString() ?? "";
             string comment = "Log file attachment";
             string basePath = @"D:\a\1\s\TestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Logs";
             string fileName = $"CreateTnMProjectTest_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.txt";
             string fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
          
             await devOpsUploader.UploadLogFile(runId, testCaseResultId, fullPath, comment);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred while uploading log file: {ex.Message}");
         }
     }).Wait();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred while running asynchronous operations: {ex.Message}");
 }

and here is our uploading method
public async Task UploadLogFile(string runId, string testCaseResultId, string logFilePath, string comment)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(logFilePath);
    string fileContentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
    var streamContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain");

    var attachment = new
    {
        stream = fileContentBase64,
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(logFilePath),
        comment,
        attachmentType = "GeneralAttachment"
    };
    string attachmentJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attachment);
    var content = new StringContent(attachmentJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    string apiUrl = $"_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=6.0-preview.1";
    string fullUrl = client.BaseAddress + apiUrl;

    var response = await client.PostAsync(fullUrl, content);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseHeaders = response.Headers.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"Response Headers: {responseHeaders}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Response Content: {responseContent}");
        string errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new Exception($"Failed to upload log file: {errorMessage}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Status Code: {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
    }
}
public string GetLatestRunId(string pat)
{
    string organization = "*******";
    string project = "Training";

    // Construct the URL for fetching test runs
    string apiUrl = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs";

    // Initialize HttpClient
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Set up HttpClient headers (authentication may be required)
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{pat}")));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");


        // Perform HTTP GET request to fetch test runs
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;

        // Check if the response is successful
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var testRunData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        // Deserialize the response content into a collection of Run objects
        var runs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestRunCollection>(testRunData);
        // Ensure there are runs available
        if (runs != null && runs.Count > 0)
        {
            // Sort the runs by StartTime in descending order to get the latest run first
            var latestRun = runs.OrderByDescending(r => r.StartTime).First();

            // Return the ID of the latest run
            return latestRun.Id.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No test runs found.");
        }
    }
}
public async Task<List<TestResult>> FetchTestResults(string runId)
{
    string organization = "********";
    string project = "Training";
    string apiUrl = $"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results?api-version=6.0-preview.1";

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string pat = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{pat}")));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var testResultData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var testResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(testResultData);

        List<TestResult> resultList = new List<TestResult>();

        foreach (var result in testResults)
        {
            // Create a new TestCase object
            var testCase = new TestCase { Name = result.testCase.name };

            // Create a new TestResult object and add it to the list
            resultList.Add(new TestResult(testCase)
            {
                Id = result.id,
                Outcome = result.outcome,
                RunId = runId
            }) ;
        }

        return resultList.Select(result => new TestResult(
       new TestCase { Name = result.TestCase.Name }
   )
        {
            Id = result.Id,
            Outcome = result.Outcome,
            RunId = runId // Add this line 
        }).ToList();
    };
    }

Tried the above approach, however we do not see any files getting uploaded. The files are getting generated but not uploading to the attachments.enter image description here`

Hi @PavanPeshve, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to locate the test run and results by build and attach files accordingly? Hope the information help resolve your query and cheers!

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT, Yes, It was helpful. I was indeed trying to access the runid while VSTest was executing and that was causing the blocker for us. The solution by you helped.

Thanks for your taking time to share the update. Glad to help and cheers!

During my test with this API in local PowerShell, it works to create attachment file to the test result of the VSTest pipeline task. It seems that you haven't located the correct test result or test run.
For this, it is suggested using this API to get test results (including test run id) by BuildId and using another API to add test result attachment. In my sample below, I have called the API requests in a PowerShell script after VSTest step, as we are unable to locate the test run until the VSTest step completes with test results published.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  orgName: ${{ split(variables['System.CollectionUri'], '/')[3] }} # Split orgName from URL like https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
  displayName: DotNet Restore
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
  displayName: VS Build
- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  displayName: VS Test
  continueOnError: true
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "orgName is $(orgName)"

    # Generate attachment file for test
    New-Item -Path "TestAttachmentFile-$(Build.BuildId).txt" -ItemType File -Value "TestAttachmentFile-$(Build.BuildId)"
    cat TestAttachmentFile-$(Build.BuildId).txt

    # Call Rest APIs authenticating against System.AccessToken 
    $headers = @{
        'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"
        'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    }
    
    Write-Host "================1. Get test results by Build.BuildId:================"
    # Resultsbybuild - List GET https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testresults/resultsbybuild?buildId={buildId}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
    $testResultsByBuildURL= "https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/$(orgName)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/testresults/resultsbybuild?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)&api-version=7.1-preview.1"
    $testResultsByBuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $testResultsByBuildURL -Headers $headers
    
    # Filter test results by test case title and extract test result ID
    $testCaseTitle = "SucceededTest"
    $targetTestResult = $testResultsByBuild.value | Where-Object { $_.testCaseTitle -eq $testCaseTitle }
    if ($targetTestResult) {
        $testResultId = $targetTestResult.id
        $testRunId = $targetTestResult.runId
        Write-Host "Test Result ID for '$testCaseTitle' of Test Run(id:$testRunId): $testResultId"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Test Result '$testResultName' not found."
    }

    Write-Host "================2. Create attachment for test result:================"
    # Attachments - Create Test Result Attachment POST https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testresults/runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=7.1-preview.1
    $addAttachmentURL = "https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/$(orgName)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/testresults/runs/$testRunId/results/$testResultId/attachments?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
    
    $FilePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestAttachmentFile-$(Build.BuildId).txt"
    $FileContent = Get-Content $FilePath -Raw
    $fileContentInBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($FileContent)
    $fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentInBytes)

    $body = @{
        'stream' = $fileContentEncoded
        'fileName' = 'TestAttachmentFile-$(Build.BuildId).txt'
        'comment' = 'Create attachment for test result from $(Build.BuildId)'
        'attachmentType' = 'GeneralAttachment'
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $addAttachmentURL -Headers $headers -Body $body
  displayName: Use APIs to locate and create attachment to test result





